# rails find_by not working as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So i have this url in a database, I'm wanting to match one url to one in a column.

I've got this at the moment.

```
brand = @event.brandurl
@brandresults = Brand.find_by_aw_deep_link(brand)
```

The column name in the table is obviously called aw_deep_link.

Why is this not working? `@brandresults` is `nil`.

Comment: Actually `find_by_` is deprecated. Use `find_by(aw_deep_link: brand)` instead

Comment: If it returns nil, it means there is no record matching that value. Print out the value and double check a record exists in the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try `Brand.find_by(aw_deep_link: brand)`

Comment: is there a find_all by?

Comment: you can use, Brand.where(aw_deep_link: brand), find_by will always return a single result (the first one that matches)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code.

```
brand = @event.brandurl    
Brand.find_by(aw_deep_link: brand)
```